# CSS bottom border transition - expand from bottom right and Top

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, transition

I need to add a touch of changes to my site. as of now when somebody Hover over the category box or button the border color changes with transition. I would like the transition happen from bottom right to left and bottom right to top right. I want to achieve transition like this in the website : [border transition example](https://gaviaspreview.com/wp/funden/projects/)

so the transition/animation expanding border from bottom right to left and bottom right to top is that possible with CSS?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @Cedric , I have Seen this transition on a website, I am sharing the link so you will get an idea what I want .Here is the link  https://gaviaspreview.com/wp/funden/projects/

Answer (score 0):

I have done it!, Incase anyone know what the answer is so I am sharing it. I have to achieve the border from bottom and right side on mouse hover, after so many tries and googling here is what it is

```css
.card{
            width: 400px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: aqua;
            position: relative;
        }
        .card::before{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0;
            width: 0;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: green;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }
        .card::after{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 10px;
            height: 0;
            background-color: green;
            transition: all 0.6s;
        }
        .card:hover::before{
            width: 100%;
        }
    
        .card:hover::after{
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="card"></div>
</body>
```